# What is the point of Validators.nullValidator(control: AbstractControl)?

Tags: angular, validation

I'm working on form validation in Angular and while reading the API I came across [nullValidator](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#nullvalidator). It says it's a "Validator that performs no operation.", which sounds to me like it is a validator that doesn't actually do anything. When I checked the [code on github](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/validators.ts#L328), this turned out to be correct. It just returns null.

So my question is, why does nullValidator exist? What purpose does it serve?

Comment: @trichetriche they say for questions I should use stackoverflow, see https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#question

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One use case comes to mind. Imagine that you have function that should return `ValidatorFn`. You might be in situation that in some cases it is reasonable to return validator that does nothing. E.g.:

```
getValidator(): ValidatorFn {
    if(someCondition) {
        return realValidator;
    }
    return Validators.nullValidator;
}
```

It also represents [null object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern) which prevents null pointers/null guards in your code as you can have always some validator even when it does nothing.